# automate the second window with selenium with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have to automate a program, when logging in, a second window opens, in this the whole program opens. I'm trying to automate the second window, but it doesn't let me, I don't know how it can be done, since it allows me to close the window, but it doesn't let me click inside the window.

```
String driverPath = "C:\\\\geckodriver-master\\\\GeckoDriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
         WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://192.168.1.210/Panacea/LogOnForm.aspx");

        String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println("Current Window: "+currentWindow);

        driver.findElement(By.id("UserNameTextBox_I")).sendKeys("jtabaresg");;
        driver.findElement(By.id("PasswordTextBox_I")).sendKeys("Panacea1");;
        WebElement clickElement = driver.findElement(By.id("ImageButton1"));  
        clickElement.click();

        ArrayList<String> handle = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        System.out.println("Handle list:"+ handle);

        for(String item: handle) {
            driver.switchTo().window(item);
            System.out.println("This is the page with title: "+driver.getTitle());
            //driver.switchTo().frame(2);


        }

       // driver.findElement(By.name("CLINICA EL PRADO ")).click();
       driver.findElement(By.name("CLINICA")).click();
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> handle = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
     System.out.println("Handle list:"+ handle);

     for(String item: handle) {
      if (!item.equals(currentWindow)) {
             driver.switchTo().window(item);
             System.out.println("Handle list:"+ handle);
             driver.close();
           }    
      
      
     }
    
  
     
    // driver.findElement(By.name("CLINICA EL PRADO ")).click();
    
   
     
    // driver.close(); // close newly opened window when done with it
     driver.switchTo().window(currentWindow);

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you only have 2 handles.

If you only have two handles, you need to add a conditional to the window you are switching to.

```
 for(String item: handle) {
        if (!item.equals(currentWindow)) {
          driver.switchTo().window(item);
          System.out.println("This is the page with title: "+driver.getTitle());
        }
 }
```

Also, I am assuming this line is not working the way you wish to see it.

`System.out.println("Handle list:"+ handle);`

Look up how to print out a list of strings.

Comment: I did what he told me, but the problem is that he doesn't let me use
  driver.findElement (By.name ("CLINICATE THE PRADO")). click ();

Just let me close the 2 window. What I want is to interact with the 2 window. Click the buttons, but just let me close the window

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an ArrayList? I doubt it's being populated with the string handles that way. 

try using a Set instead of ArrayList...

Set handles = driver.getWindowHandles();

Comment: I tried but nothing, I mean if I put driver.close () if I close the window, but what I want is to interact with that window, select elements

Comment: Set<String>  handles1 =driver.getWindowHandles(); 
Iterator<String> it = handles1.iterator(); //iterate through your windows 
while (it.hasNext()){ String parent = it.next(); 
String newwin = it.next();
driver.switchTo().window(newwin);//perform actions on new window 
driver.switchTo().frame("content");

driver.findElement(By.name("Aceptar")).click();

driver.close();
driver.switchTo().window(parent); }
}

Comment: Make sure to not switch to the original handle, add a conditional before you switch